# Setting ManagedBean values in another ManagedBean's method

Tags: jsf-2

If I am navigating from page one to page two, When I click on Page one's submit button, control goes to the managed bean written corresponding to page one, I want to fetch some result from database and show them to page two, If I set the Database values into the Managed bean corresponding to page two in the first Managed Bean's action method, then will I be able to get those on page two.

Please suggest if my approach is right?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject let's say bean named Bean1 into Bean2 this way

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public Bean2 {
     @ManagedProperty(value="#{bean1}")//this is EL name of your bean 
     private Bean1 injectedBean;

     public void setBean1(Bean1 value) {
          injectedBean = value; //provide setter for it
     }

     @PostConstruct
     private void init() {
         List<YourData> list = injectedBean.getDBData(); //now you can fetch your list
     }
```

Note that you have to provide setter for injection and scope of the injected bean should be always same or higher then the your beans scope (in this case Bean1 has to be at least RequestScope)

P.S. Also you could have some kind of DAO bean which could do all the database database operations for you (it can be EJB bean or even JSF Managed Bean) and then inject it to every ManagedBean which will require cooperation with your DB.

Comment: Actually I have a xhtml page, on click of submit button , I need to display a set of records on the next page. in these two pages, two managed beans are involved. after I click on submit button, first managed bean's action method is called where I am having the list of values and I want to show those list of values on the second page. Can you please help me how can I do that

Comment: I mean how can I set that list in the next managed bean's property

Comment: And what should be the scope of that bean

Comment: You have two options: make that bean ViewScoped and show your list on the same page. Or move fetching your values to another bean which will be bound to the second page and show your values there. Is there any connection between first and the second page?